# How to understand the "of somebody" part

Tags: complements

> It is recounted **of Thomas Carlyle** that when he heard of the illness of his friend, Henry Taylor, he went off immediately to visit him, carrying with him in his pocket what remained of a bottle of medicine formerly prescribed for an indisposition of Mrs. Carlyle's.

I know **it** in the above clause is the dummy subject, and the real subject is the that-clause. The whole sentence is not hard to understand in its current form. But I have some difficulty explaining the "**of Thomas Carlyle**" part **grammatically** in the above sentence. Is it a subject complement or an adverbial complement? What's its modifier?

Comment: I don't think it's a complement at all. *It is recounted that when he heard...* would be grammatical - you would just need an antecedent for the *he* somewhere else, say in the previous sentence. I'd say it's an adjunct of *recounted* in the form of a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @Minty, thank you very much, got it. Your idea is very similar to Kris's below.

Comment: If by *sb* you mean *somebody*, please spell out the actual word.

Answer (score 1):

### Sentence is in the passive voice

What you seem to have missed is that this is a passive-voice sentence, which causes the object to move ahead of the verb. (for example: "{S:people} {V:tell} {O:the story}" -> "{O:the story} {V:is told}")

### Dummy-*it* can also be an object

Rather than a subject, "*it*" is in fact a dummy *object* for the verb "**[to recount](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recount)**" (meaning 1.). Substitution of an object with a dummy pronoun is rare, and only makes sense in cases where the verb object is predictable.  (note that only "it" can do this; "there" cannot be used as a object-substitute)

This example is acceptable to readers because this meaning of "to recount" only ever takes a very small set of nouns as a object, and they all mean the same thing: a story. When your readers already know what the object is going to be, you don't have to explicitly state it.  If you *did* want to restore the object, the sentence would read like this:

- **A story is recounted** of Thomas Carlyle that when he heard of the illness...

The main clause is in boldface. Once you see that this is a passive sentence, and have identifed the object of the main clause as "a story", then it's obvious that "of Thomas Carlyle" is just a common-or-garden subclause with no real significance, and one that can be deleted from the sentence with no grammatical problems:

- A story is recounted <s>of Thomas Carlyle</s> that when he heard of the illness of ...

Of course, this leaves a dangling pronoun (who is "he"?), but that can simply be expanded to "Thomas Carlyle" without changing the structure of the sentence:

- A story is recounted that when <s>he</s>**Thomas Carlyle** heard of the illness of ...